# Is there a symfony console command for opening a php cli console?

Tags: symfony

with Drupal you have a drush command to open a php cli console with Drupal loaded in the environment. `drush php:cli`.

I could not find on Google any post, article, github repo or so on that?

Could enlight me a little?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Symfony doesn't have anything like drush `php:cli` out of the box, but there might be some open-source extensions. Which particular goal do you want to achieve with this functionality in Symfony?

Comment: Thanks for your response Kyrylo. I've installed stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle and configured an Doctrine entity with the Timestamptable Trait. AFAIK the whole thing works with registered Doctrine events listeners. When an entity is persisted the event listener then set current datetime in the configured entity fields. When I create and persist my timestamptable entity in my tests i 've a not null constraint violation on the createdAt column. So I first want to check if TimestamptableListener is registered so why i want to use Doctrine\Common\EventManager to get the list.